# Save the position of the thumb of SeekBar

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any way for me to save the position of the thumb where i have moved to before i leave the fragment which is contenting that SeekBar ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the position of the `Seekbar` in `SharedPreference` and then retrieve it later.

Here is the simple example

**EXAMPLE:**

```
SharedPreference mSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor mEditor = mSharedPrefs.edit();
int mProgress = mSeekBar.getProgress();
mEditor.putInt("SeekBarPosition", mProgress).commit();
```

and then retrieve them like this

```
int mProgress = mSharedPrefs.getInt("mMySeekBarProgress", 0);
mSeekBar.setProgress(mProgress);
```

Comment: sorry i'm a newbie to android , can u make it more clearly a little bit , thanks !

Comment: I have given you sample, you should study about how to save values to `SharedPreference`, the first snippet of code is to save the values when you close fragment and second snippet is to get the value back, you can use first method in `onPause()` and second in `onResume()`.

Comment: Thanks , i got it ! Your code is totally work for me ! Thanks so much

Comment: glad I could help :) always accept and upvote answers that helps you :)

Comment: and do you know how to remove data from SharedPreference ? i have tried mSharedPreference.remove("key").commit , but before that i have set the position of the thumb of SeekBar to middle , and when i used the code above then the position of SeekBar went to end of left side.

Comment: To remove them all SharedPreferences.Editor.clear() followed by a commit()

Comment: yes i have used that code , but would you mind looking again my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You should define **static int value**.